# LINQ To XML Query using descendatns

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I want to query the following xml file using LINQ To XML

```
<table>
 <row>
  <cell>
    <content>x</content>
  <cell>
  <cell>
    <content>y</content>
  <cell>
  <cell>
    <foo>
     <bar>x</bar>
    </foo>
  <cell>
 <row>
</table>
```

Im trying to get all cell nodes that have a descendant with the value 'x'. In this example two cell nodes should be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Any` extension method to see if any of the descendents of cell have the correct value.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("somefile.xml");
var cells = from cell in doc.Descendants("cell")
            where cell.Descendants().Any(v => v.Value == "x")
            select cell;
```

Comment: what about "x" under element "bar"?

Comment: I expect two results (including the cell that contains x under bar)

Comment: @markus: I have modified my answer, it should give the correct result now.